# Issue with converting rows into a single row

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe and I want to transpose rows with the same ID into a single row:

```
ID   TYPE1   TYPE2  GROUP STARTIME
1    A       C      Q1    10:25 
1    A       C      Q2    11:00
1    A       C      Q3    11:30
2    B       D      Y1    12:00
2    B       D      Y2    12:30
```

The result should be:

```
ID   TYPE1   TYPE2   G1   G2  G3   START_G1   START_G2   START_G3
1    A       C       Q1   Q2  Q3   10:25      11:00      11:30
2    B       D       Y1   Y2  NaN  12:00      12:30      NaN
```

This is my current code:

```
df_transposed = df.pivot_table(index= ['ID','GROUP']).unstack()
df_transposed = df_transposed.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df_transposed.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df_transposed]
df_transposed = df_transposed.reset_index(level=0)
df_transposed.head()
```

But columns `TYPE1` and `TYPE2` are repeated 3 times for ID 1 and 2 times for ID 2. I want them to be a single column as shown in the expected result, because they always have the same value for the same ID. Also, I get columns like `GROUP_Q1`, but I'd like to get `Group_1`, `Group_2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counting groups:

```
df_transposed = df.pivot_table(index= ['ID','TYPE1', 'TYPE2'], 
                               columns=df.groupby(['ID','TYPE1', 'TYPE2']).cumcount() + 1, 
                               values=['GROUP','STARTIME'], aggfunc='first')
df_transposed.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df_transposed]
print (df_transposed)
               GROUP_1 GROUP_2 GROUP_3 STARTIME_1 STARTIME_2 STARTIME_3
ID TYPE1 TYPE2                                                         
1  A     C          Q1      Q2      Q3      10:25      11:00      11:30
2  B     D          Y1      Y2    None      12:00      12:30       None
```

If need rename columns:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'GROUP':'G','STARTIME':'START'})
df_transposed = df.pivot_table(index= ['ID','TYPE1', 'TYPE2'], 
                               columns=df.groupby(['ID','TYPE1', 'TYPE2']).cumcount() + 1, 
                               values=['G','START'], aggfunc='first')
df_transposed.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df_transposed]
print (df_transposed.reset_index())
   ID TYPE1 TYPE2 G_1 G_2   G_3 START_1 START_2 START_3
0   1     A     C  Q1  Q2    Q3   10:25   11:00   11:30
1   2     B     D  Y1  Y2  None   12:00   12:30    None
```